# How to generate this word "Dokumacılar" in Latex?

Tags: symbols, characters

Disclaimer: I have nothing to do with ISIS

After 2 years of using Latex I have finally met my match.

I want to generate the short "i" thing in the word Dokumacılar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dokumac%C4%B1lar

How? It seems to be impossible! I have no idea the origin of this character. Please help!

Comment: Can't you just copy paste? Shouldn't be a problem with utf8.

Comment: @Johannes_B It won't show up when the latex code is compiled. Does it show up with yours?

Comment: the classic markup is `\i` but if using inputenc then ı should work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle life saver. Submitting a draft in 1 hour and someone has that character in his name in the references LoL.

Comment: The character is standard in Turkish, at least. It's a dotless i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

some word ending in macılar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, I don't have that package

Comment: @Sheppy yes, you do. It is part of the base latex distribution, if you have latex at all, you have that.

Comment: I meant I haven't loaded it yet

Comment: @Sheppy -- if you *don't* have the `inputenc` package, then your latex installation shouldn't work at all.  it's included in the "basic" set of packages, at least some of which are needed by every document class i know of, so loading anything less than the basic set is counterproductive.